# JQuery attribute selector: wildcard for inner char

Tags: jquery

I've searched all the way down on the internet but I wasn't able to find what I looking for.

Let's say I have some inputs like those

```
<input name="kpr-xx-yyyy-mm-dd" />
<input name="kpr-zz-yyyy-mm-dd" />
<input name="kpr-kk-yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

where `xx`, `zz`, `kk` are some numeric id(s).

I would like to select all inputs that have name as `kpr-*-yyyy-mm-dd`

As far as I know, there isn't a "wildcard" selector for inner chars of a string.

I've tried with

```
$("input[name*=kpr][name*="+yyyy+"][name*="+mm+"][name*="+dd+"]");
```

maybe I can reach what I'm searching for, but I would like to restrict possible errors and search only for string I need (so same order, that in my example isn't taken into account)

Any ideas?

PS.: I don't know pretty much of jQuery, maybe solution is very simple and I don't know but, what I'm sure is that the www hasn't much about ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine a [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector with an [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector (the *ends with* needs to be a single selector like `$='2012-12-12'` rather than 3 separate selectors, hence the concatenation:

```
$("input[name^='kpr-'][name$='" + yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + "']");
```

I added inner single-quotes as your selectors have special characters (e.g. the '-')

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r1xayf1t/